# Возникает ошибка "Segmentation fault" совершенно не понимаю из за чего она возникла и как её "поймать"

Tags: c

Выпрыгивает ошибка "Segmentation fault"  **совершенно не понимаю как её поймать**. Также не понимаю почему она возникает.

Вот код :

```
#include "util.h"

#include <errno.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <net/if.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>

#include <linux/can.h>
#include <linux/can/bcm.h>

#define PROGNAME "socketcan-bcm-demo"
#define VERSION  "1.0.0"

#define MSGID   (0x0BC)
#define NFRAMES (1)

#define DELAY (10000)

static sig_atomic_t sigval;

static void onsig(int val)
{
    sigval = (sig_atomic_t)val;
    printf("onsig(int val)\n");
}

static void usage(void)
{
    puts("Usage: " PROGNAME "[OPTIONS] IFACE\n"
         "Where:\n"
         "  IFACE    CAN network interface\n"
         "Options:\n"
         "  -h       Display this help then exit\n"
         "  -v       Display version info then exit\n");
}

static void version(void)
{
    puts(PROGNAME " " VERSION "\n");
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    // -- преднастройка н --
    int flags, opt;
    int s;
    char *iface;
    struct sockaddr_can addr;
    struct ifreq ifr;
    printf("1 !!!\n");


    struct can_msg
    {
        /**
         * struct bcm_msg_head - заголовок для сообщений в/из  менеджера сообщений (the broadcast manager)
         * @opcode:    код операции (opcodе), see enum below.
         * @flags:     специальные флаги, see below.
         * @count:     количество кадров для отправки до изменения интервала.
         * @ival1:     интервал для первых @count сообщений.
         * @ival2:     интервал для следующих кадров.
         * @can_id:    CAN ID для получения либо отправки кадров
         * @nframes:   номер кадров поднятых для присоединения к загаловку
         * @frames:    массив CAN кадров.
         */

        /**
         * struct can_frame - базовая CAN структура
         * @can_id:  идетификационный номер кан сообщения
         * @can_dlc: размерсообщения от 0 до 8 байт
         * @__pad:   "набивка :3"
         * @__res0:  "зарезервированно"
         * @__res1:  "зарезервированно"
         * @data:    само кан сообщение
         */

        struct bcm_msg_head msg_head;
        struct can_frame frame[NFRAMES];
    } msg;

    // поднимаю кан протокол 
    system("ip link set can0 type can bitrate 125000 ");
    printf("ip link set %s type can bitrate %d \n", "can0", 125000);
    system("ip link set can0 up");

    // Регистация сигнальных прерывателей
    if (signal(SIGINT, onsig)    == SIG_ERR ||
        signal(SIGTERM, onsig)   == SIG_ERR ||
        signal(SIGCHLD, SIG_IGN) == SIG_ERR)
    {
        perror(PROGNAME);
        return errno;
    }

    printf("2 !!!\n"); // в этом блоке(2-3) происходит ошибка !!!!!!!
    // Открытие кан интерфейса
    s = socket(PF_CAN, SOCK_DGRAM, CAN_BCM);
    if (s < 0)
    {
        perror(PROGNAME ": socket \"не отработал\" ");
        return errno;
    }

    strncpy(ifr.ifr_name, iface, IFNAMSIZ);
    if (ioctl(s, SIOCGIFINDEX, &ifr) < 0) // сист выз при извл. САНа из компа то выпрыгнет ошибка
    {
        perror(PROGNAME ": ioctl");
        return errno;
    }

    addr.can_family = AF_CAN;
    addr.can_ifindex = ifr.ifr_ifindex;
    if (connect(s, (struct sockaddr *)&addr, sizeof(addr)) < 0)
    {
        perror(PROGNAME ": connect \"не отработал\" ");
        return errno;
    }

    printf("3 !!!\n");
    // Настройка сокета неблокирующим
    flags = fcntl(s, F_GETFL, 0);
    if (flags < 0)
    {
        perror(PROGNAME ": fcntl: F_GETFL");
        return errno;
    }

    if (fcntl(s, F_SETFL, flags | O_NONBLOCK) < 0)
    {
        perror(PROGNAME ": fcntl: F_SETFL");
        return errno;
    }

    // -- преднастройка к -- 

    // настраиваем сообщение
    sigval = 0;

    msg.msg_head.opcode  = RX_SETUP;
    msg.msg_head.can_id  = 0x123;
    msg.msg_head.flags   = 0;
    msg.msg_head.nframes = 0;

    if (write(s, &msg, sizeof(msg)) < 0)
    {
        perror(PROGNAME ": write: RX_SETUP \"не отработал\" ");
        return errno;
    }

    printf("while !!!\n");
    //основной цикл
    int tex_per = 0;
    while (0 == sigval)
  {
        ssize_t nbytes;

        if(tex_per == 0)
            printf("read 5!\n");

        // Чтение из КАН интерфейса
        nbytes = read(s, &msg, sizeof(msg));
        if (nbytes < 0)
        {
            if (errno != EAGAIN)
            {
                perror(PROGNAME ": read \"не отработал\" ");
            }

            usleep(DELAY);
        }
        else if (nbytes < (ssize_t)sizeof(msg))
        {
            fputs(PROGNAME ": read: не полное BCM сообщение \n", stderr);
            usleep(DELAY);
        }
        else
        {
            struct can_frame * const frame = msg.frame;
            unsigned char * const data = frame->data;
            const unsigned int dlc = frame->can_dlc;
            unsigned int i;

            // распечатать полученный кадр
            printf("RX:  ");
            print_can_frame(frame);
            printf("\n");

            // модифицируем CAN кадр, чтобы использовать наш идентификатор(ID) сообщения
            frame->can_id = MSGID;

            // Увеличить значение каждого байта в кадре CAN
            for (i = 0; i < dlc; ++i)
            {
                data[i] += 1;
            }

            /* Set a TX message for sending this frame once */

            // Установить TX-сообщение для отправки "этого" кадра один раз
            msg.msg_head.opcode  = TX_SEND;
            msg.msg_head.can_id  = 0;
            msg.msg_head.flags   = 0;
            msg.msg_head.nframes = 1;

            // записать сообщение в буфер
            nbytes = write(s, &msg, sizeof(msg));
            if (nbytes < 0)
            {
                perror(PROGNAME ": write: TX_SEND непрошло сообщение");
            }
            else if (nbytes < (ssize_t)sizeof(msg))
            {
                fputs(PROGNAME ": write: неполное BCM сообщение \n", stderr);
            }
            else
            {
                // Распечатать переданный CAN кадр
                printf("TX:  ");
                print_can_frame(frame);
                printf("\n");
            }
        }
    }

    puts("\nGoodbye!");

    // Закрытие КАН интерфейса
    if (close(s) < 0)
    {
        perror(PROGNAME ": close ошибка закрытия интерфейса ");
        return errno;
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

**В этом блоке происходит ошибка, но увы я непонимаю почему ;_;** :

```
// Открытие кан интерфейса
s = socket(PF_CAN, SOCK_DGRAM, CAN_BCM);
if (s < 0)
{
    perror(PROGNAME ": socket \"не отработал\" ");
    return errno;
}

strncpy(ifr.ifr_name, iface, IFNAMSIZ);
if (ioctl(s, SIOCGIFINDEX, &ifr) < 0) // системный вызов  при извл. САНа из компа то выпрыг ошибка
{
    perror(PROGNAME ": ioctl");
    return errno;
}

addr.can_family = AF_CAN;
addr.can_ifindex = ifr.ifr_ifindex;
if (connect(s, (struct sockaddr *)&addr, sizeof(addr)) < 0)
{
    perror(PROGNAME ": connect \"не отработал\" ");
    return errno;
}
```

При отработки кода , отрабатывает сигнальный прерыватель и пишет "развал памяти":

```
// Регистация сигнальных прерывателей
if (signal(SIGINT, onsig)    == SIG_ERR ||
    signal(SIGTERM, onsig)   == SIG_ERR ||
    signal(SIGCHLD, SIG_IGN) == SIG_ERR)
{
    perror(PROGNAME);
    return errno;
}
```

Вот вывод программы :

```
# ./tream
1 !!!
ip link set can0 type can bitrate 125000
2 !!!
Segmentation fault
```

вот вывод **gdb**:

```
(gdb) run
Starting program: /mnt/usb/novosib_test_2/tream_g
1 !!!
ip link set can0 type can bitrate 125000
2 !!!

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
__GI___strnlen (
    str=str@entry=0x130 <error: Cannot access memory at address 0x130>,
    maxlen=maxlen@entry=16) at strnlen.c:120
120     strnlen.c: No such file or directory.
(gdb) l 100
95      in strnlen.c
(gdb) l 120
115     strnlen.c: No such file or directory.
```

Comment: Дампните core и посмотрите через gdb/xxgdb, предварительно скомпилировав с -g. По крайней мере, сразу увидите строку, на которой падает.

Comment: Что такое `strncpy(ifr.ifr_name, iface, IFNAMSIZ);`? Где инициализируется `iface`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Спасибо @AnT .

Объявил  `iface = "can0";` И всё заработало, странно не ошидал что от невыполнения объявления происходит такая ошибка `Segmentation fault`

```
// -- пред настройка н --
int flags, opt;
int s;
char *iface;
struct sockaddr_can addr;
struct ifreq ifr;
printf("1 !!!\n");


struct can_msg
{
    /**
     * struct bcm_msg_head - заголовок для сообщений в/из  менеджера сообщений (the broadcast manager)
     * @opcode:    код операции (opcodе), see enum below.
     * @flags:     специальные флаги, see below.
     * @count:     количество кадров для отправки до изменения интервала.
     * @ival1:     интервал для первых @count сообщений.
     * @ival2:     интервал для следующих кадров.
     * @can_id:    CAN ID для получения либо отправки кадров
     * @nframes:   номер кадров поднятых для присоединения к загаловку
     * @frames:    массив CAN кадров.
     */

    /**
     * struct can_frame - базовая CAN структура
     * @can_id:  идетификационный номер кан сообщения
     * @can_dlc: размерсообщения от 0 до 8 байт
     * @__pad:   "набивка :3"
     * @__res0:  "зарезервированно"
     * @__res1:  "зарезервированно"
     * @data:    само кан сообщение
     */

    struct bcm_msg_head msg_head;
    struct can_frame frame[NFRAMES];
} msg;



system("ip link set can0 type can bitrate 125000 ");
printf("ip link set %s type can bitrate %d \n", "can0", 125000);
system("ip link set can0 up");

iface = "can0";

// Регистрация сигнальных прерывателей
// работа с сигналами непонятна разобрать более подробно!!
if (signal(SIGINT, onsig)    == SIG_ERR ||
        signal(SIGTERM, onsig)   == SIG_ERR ||
        signal(SIGCHLD, SIG_IGN) == SIG_ERR)
{
    perror(PROGNAME);
    return errno;
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]